# min-height to chart container if no data with highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, highcharts

I am setting up this bar graph where I need to create a scroll window to view the entire data set, the main container is set to 500px this is set to overflow scroll., the problem is when there's no data, the entire graph container is changing it's height to zero, since I am resizing the container dynamically based on the number of points.

Is there an easy way to keep the container to lets say minHeigh: 500px within highcharts.js?

This is my js:

```
chart: {
                    type: "bar",
                    backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
                    borderColor: "#fff",
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderRadius: 2,
                    spacing: [4, 40, 10, 3],
                    className: "main-graph",
                    height: 34 * (n_categories) + 69, //getting this value dynamically based on many items I have in chart, but if no data how to keep value to min-height:500px?
                    renderTo: 'mainChart',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null
                },
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe236652/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: ((n_categories)?(34 * (n_categories) + 69):500),`

Comment: brilliant solution! :)